# Many to Many three tables relationship JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm not able to define properly the relation between USER,SOCIEDAD and AREAS.

When I try to save a user, it does :
Hibernate: insert into npro_usuarios (activo, email_usuario, fecha_ultimo_acceso, matricula_usuario, nombre_usuario, observaciones, usuario_modif, id_usuario) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) -- That is correct

but later try to insert in the join table (id_user, id_sociedad, id_area)

Insert into npro_usuarios_sociedades_areas (id_usuario, id_area) values (?, ?)

And fail because it is not providing id_sociedad

ORA-01400: it can't insert NULL in ("NPROUSER"."NPRO_USUARIOS_SOCIEDADES_AREAS"."ID_SOCIEDAD")

What is wrong in the definition?

USER:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NPRO_USUARIOS")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1330075515340995797L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="user_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="user_seq_gen", sequenceName="TELCO_NPRO_USER_SEQ")
    @NotNull
    private int id_usuario;

    @NotNull
    private String nombre_usuario;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinTable(name = "NPRO_USUARIOS_SOCIEDADES_AREAS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_sociedad"))
    private Set<Sociedad> listaSociedad;

    @Transient
    private String sociedades;

    // Si el area es nula, el usuario estara asignado a todas las areas
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinTable(name = "NPRO_USUARIOS_SOCIEDADES_AREAS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_area"))
    private Set<Area> listAreas;

    @Transient
    private String areas;

    @NotNull
    private String matricula_usuario;

    @NotNull
    private String email_usuario;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinTable(name = "NPRO_PERFILES_USUARIOS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_rol"))
    private Set<Role> listaRoles;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinTable(name = "NPRO_PERFILES_USUARIOS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_pantalla"))
    private Set<Pantalla> listaPantallas;

    private LocalDateTime fecha_ultimo_acceso;
    private String observaciones;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_modif")
    private User usuario_modif;
}
```

Compnay:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NPRO_MAESTRO_SOCIEDADES")
public class Sociedad implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    private int id_sociedad;
    @NotNull
    private String cod_sociedad;
    @NotNull
    private String cod_sociedad_gl;
    @NotNull
    private String nombre_sociedad;
    @NotNull
    private String cif_sociedad;
    private String observaciones;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_modif")
    private User usuario_modif;

    private String activo;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinTable(name = "NPRO_USUARIOS_SOCIEDADES_AREAS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_sociedad"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario"))
    private Set<User> listaUsuarios;
}
```

Area:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NPRO_MAESTRO_AREAS")
public class Area implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1330075515340995797L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="area_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="area_seq_gen", sequenceName="TELCO_NPRO_AREAS_SEQ")
    @NotNull
    private int id_area;

    @NotNull
    private String nombre_area;

    private LocalDateTime fecha_modif;
    private String observaciones;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_modif")
    private User usuario_modif;

    @NotNull
    private String activo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_sociedad")
    private Sociedad sociedad;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinTable(name = "NPRO_USUARIOS_SOCIEDADES_AREAS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_area"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario"))
    private Set<User> listaUsuarios;
    }
```

I'm using springboot jpa repository save method

```
@Override
public User save(User user) {

    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Comment: How you create database like hibernate-auto ddl ?

Answer (score 0):

The hibernate will create join table with foreign keys which are the key of joining tables. So the id cannot be null. If you want null value. I suggest you create relational entity and map one to many from joining tables

Comment: I dont want null values, hibernate is triying to insert null in the join table. Join tables has  (id_user, id_sociedad, id_area) keys, and hibeante is populating only id_user, and id_area

Comment: Insert into npro_usuarios_sociedades_areas (id_usuario, id_area) values (?, ?) i see you are inserting null value for the remaining column. Did you do it on purpose ?

Comment: No, this is hibernate doing automatically

Comment: If area is not null, it's weird

Comment: Everything is with values, User, areas and sociedades, because of that I think the problem is on the relationship definition, because is three thables many to many...